# How can i make asymmetric cron job in linux?

Tags: php, linux, cron, cpanel

I want to make asymmetric scheduled cron job.

My cPanel allows to make it like "x times for per min/hour/day/month" etc..

But i want to make one cron job for different hours for everyday (everyday at 20.00, 20.04, 21.12, 03.00 etc).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a set of hours and minutes

```
4,12,0 20,21,03 * * * *
```

which will match 20:00, 20:04, 20:12, 21:00, 21:04, 21:12, 03:00, 03:04, 03:12

If you want to be more specific than that, you would have to use separate entries, as Wiseguy pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly.

I don't know what abilities cPanel give you, keep in mind that you can create a cron entry several times, for different purposes
Here's the cron entries that executes the script at different times.

```
#execute myjob at 20:00,20:04 every day.
0,4 20 * * *  /path/to/myjob

#execute myjob at 20:30,20:46,21:30,21:46, 22:30,22:46  every day.
30,46 20,21,22 * * *  /path/to/myjob

#execute myjob at 21:12 on Monday ,Tuesday and Wednesday
21 12 * * 1-3  /path/to/myjob

#execute myjob 15 minutes past every 3. hour on Saturday
15 */3 * * 6  /path/to/myjob
```

Read more in the [crontab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) manual